Error in if (newversion != oldversion) when Creating Package in R
I am in the process of creating a new R package and when I try to clean and install button on RStudio it, I get the following error message in the console:
> library(MY_R_PACKAGE)
Error in if (newversion != oldversion) { : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

I have a NAMESPACE file and a DESCRIPTION file. I've tried making modifications in the DESCRIPTION file by changing the package version and R version required but it doesn't resolve the issue.
Here is the text in my description file (some names changed to hide package)
Package: My_R_Package
Type: Package
Title: A package to do stuff
Version: 0.1.0
Author: My Name
Maintainer: My Name <my.name@emailservice.com>
Description: An R package to do stuff.
License: GPL-3 + file LICENSE
Encoding: UTF-8
LazyData: true
Depends: R (>= 4.4.0)
RoxygenNote: 7.3.2

I don't get any errors for devtools::check()
> devtools::check()
...
   
── R CMD check results ───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────── My_R_Package 0.1.0 ────
Duration: 5s

0 errors ✔ | 0 warnings ✔ | 0 notes ✔

I also don't get any errors with devtools::document()
What am I doing incorrectly and how can I fix it?

We can't say because you haven't shown us your DESCRIPTION file.  Have you run devtools::check() and devtools::document()?  Do you get the same error when you devtools::load_all()?  What about devtools::build()?  Please update your question with the results of running all four of these commands.  Have you tried uninstalling the currently installed version of the package and then reinstalling the latest one?

The issues was building the package on a cloud drive.
The issue was resolved after moving the folder to a drive on my local machine.
